# Передача флагов форматирования в функцию

Tags: c++

Как передать в функцию флаг форматирования `std::left`, `std::right` или `std::internal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то можно передавать их и как целые числа (точнее, перечисление) - просто нужно передавать не `std::left`, а `ios_base::left`, и использовать не в конструкции `<<`, а как параметр `setf()`. Обычно почему-то этот метод оказывается незаслуженно забыт.

Подробнее - см. [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf).

Comment: Но так же можно передать и ненужный мне флаг

Comment: Простите, но и при передаче через `iomanip` (функции и `<<`) тоже можно передать и ненужный вам флаг :) В чем вы видите принципиальную разницу?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю таким образом можно передать и несуществующий флаг

Comment: Знаете, если вы захотите, то сможете передать и указатель не на ту функцию  :) Флаги определены, находятся в перечислении. Не знаю, лично я никогда не считал проблемой, что какой-то идиот может вызвать `sqrt` для отрицательного числа...

Answer (score 2):

Например, таким образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


void f( const std::string &s, std::ios_base & flag(std::ios_base & ) )
{
    std::cout << std::setw( 20 ) << flag << s << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    f( "Hello", std::left );
    f( "Hello", std::right );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Hello               
               Hello
```

Аналогичным образом можно использовать `std::internal`

Все эти флаги, то есть функции-манипуляторы потоком, имеют одинаковое объявление

```
std::ios_base & flag(std::ios_base & ):
```

Comment: можете объяснить для чего`(std::ios_base & )`?

Comment: @god Чтобы работало.:) Эти флаги являются функциями, и вы передаете указатели на эти функции в свою программу. Эти флаги, то есть функции, имеют свой собственный параметр. Они называются манипуляторами. Проще говоря вы должны правильно указать объявление этих флагов в своей функции в качестве параметров.

Comment: странный синтаксис ну ладно спасибо

Comment: @god Это синтаксис, когда в качестве параметра объявляется функция. Например, есть функция void f( int ); И вы хотите ее передать другой функции в качестве аргумента. Тогда другая функция должна написать void g( void f( int ) ); или void g( void ( *f )( int ) );

Answer (score 2):

Если уж задаться целью передавать именно манипуляторы (вместо более гибкого и разумного варианта с флагами, предложенного @Harry), то вместо того, чтобы заниматься филигранным выписыванием конкретного типа этих манипуляторов лучше тем или иным образом полностью от него абстрагироваться

```
static_assert(
  std::is_same<decltype(std::left), decltype(std::right)>::value &&
  std::is_same<decltype(std::left), decltype(std::internal)>::value, "");

void foo(const std::string &str, decltype(std::left) alignment)
{
  std::cout << std::setw(42) << alignment << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Есть ли смысл проверять одинаковость типов? По Стандарту сигнатуры должны быть идентичны. Вместо `decltype(std::left)` возможно нагляднее будет использовать синоним типа.

Comment: @alexolut: Можно и не проверять... Это скорее не проверка, а именно формализованный комментарий: "*я знаю*, что типы этих манипуляторов идентичны". Он говорит непосвященному читателю: в объявлении параметра я использовал `decltype(std::left)` потому что не имеет значения, какой использовать. Я вообще считаю, что всевозможные assertions - это на 90% способ формализованного комментирования кода, и лишь на 10% - способ выполнения проверок.

Comment: Пока ещё не проверял, но интересно как с `decltype` в объявлении функции поведет себя какой-нибудь *doxygen*. Я бы всё же завёл синоним типа для ясности.